# Moving bat. repaint

Tags: java, methods

Hi guys I am trying to make a Halloween applet. I'm I am trying to make a bat that will move across the screen, but it just makes a line of bats. That is why I tried using repaint(), but I dont think I am using it correctly. What do I have to do to make it paint one bat and when I paint another one delete the first one?

```
for(x = 1; x < 1000; x+=x)
      {
          ramX = generator.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
          ramY = generator.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

          int paint = 0;

          for(ramX = ramX; ramX < 1350; ramX+=1)
          {  
          page.drawImage(bat, ramX, ramY, 100, 50, this);   

          paint++; 
          if (paint > 3)
              {
                  repaint(); 
                  paint = 0; 
              }
          }

      }
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling super.paintComponent or super.paint (whether you are doing this in Swing or AWT respectively). Also just as a side note, if you don't need to declare anything in any of the spots in a for loop declaration you don't need to: `for ( ; ramX < 1350; ramX += 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
@Override
public void update(Graphics g){
    paint(g);
}
```

on the applet class?